# Law of Sine Problem

Tags: trigonometry

I know the law of Sine. SinA/a=SinB/b=SinC/c

I think I'm missing something here... I am given ∠A=68.41°,∠B=54.23° and a=12.75ft. I found b with no trouble which is 11.119ft. I used SinA/a=SinB/b... But I cannot figure out how find ∠C and c.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  The angles of a triangle add to 180 degrees.  Can you take it from here?

Comment: Oh I am SO dumb! I totally forgot we learned that in class today! haha:D What would I ever do without Stack. I'll vote this up in 8mins when I'm allowed too. Thanks:)

Comment: No problem!  I'm glad you figured it out.